# Build a document-term-matrix based on most frequent terms in R

Tags: r, matrix, tm

I built a    document-term-matrix with    tm 
package in R. There are 18000 terms and most of them are not frequent. I want to remove the terms with less than 0.0001 frequency in order to decrease the number of columns.

Comment: Look at the help page for `removeSparseTerms()` if you've already made the DTM. Otherwise look at `?DocumentTermMatrx` and `?termFreq` to filter the list while making the DTM.

Comment: The qdap package also has tools for finding frequent terms and culling infrequent terms.  It co-exists well with the tm package.

Answer (score 0):

```
removeSparseTerms(DocumentTermMatrix(corpus),0.995)
```

and you can change sparse argument as you like for your problem